# Pagination in Rails: undefined method `total_pages' for []:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application I need to perform search based on some conditions. Since I have millions of records I need to perform pagination. I tried will_paginate. The output I am getting is "undefined method `total_pages' for []:Array"

My controller:

```
class TweetsController<ApplicationController
  def index
    city = params[:show]
    search_term = params[:text]        

    search_term.gsub!(/\s/, '%')
    city_coordinates = Coordinates.where('city=?', city)

    @tweets = if (city_coordinates.count == 1 && city_coordinates.first.valid_location?)
      @tweets = Tweets.for_coordinates(city_coordinates.first).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50) &  Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE?" , "%#{search_term}%").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
    else if (city_coordinates.count != 1 )
      @tweets = Tweets.for_user_location(city).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50) &  Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE?" , "%#{search_term}%").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
    else
      @tweets = Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE? ", "%#{search_term}%").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
    end
    end
  end
end
```

My view:

```
<%= will_paginate @tweets %>
<% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>
<ul>
  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>    
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_source %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_sc_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I tried using will_paginate, but it is not working. The error I am getting is "undefined method `total_pages' for []:Array". What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where does this error occur?

Comment: It says line 1 in the code for view , but I don't think there is error there

Comment: Also, please post your actual code. What you have posted here contains many errors.

Comment: this is my actual code its working perfectly without  paginaton ,but with pagination I am getting this error

Comment: To start, the syntax should be 'elsif' as opposed to 'else if'. How is this working for you?

Comment: And in your controller there's an `end` too much.

Comment: Your problem is probably occurring because you use `&` to join together two collections, turning it into an array instead of an will_paginate collection. Try if it works if you don't do that.

Comment: now I understood the mistake I have been making. I am using pagination on a function instead of a  query. For the first two conditions  I am calling the function defined in model and its not a  query query I have in model. Can u help me how to use pagination for  queries in model?

Answer (score 3):

`@tweets` is an array, and `will_paginate` doesn't work with arrays by default. To enable this behavior, add a new file in `config/initalizers` with this line:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```